# Extra line with inline if and comment

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm writing an algorithm with algorithm2e.

I want to do an inline if with `\lIf` with a comment on the same line with `\Comment*`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined,boxed,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\lIf{true}{%
    foo \Comment*{bar}
}
\caption{Test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

But it produces an extra unwanted line:
[image]

How to remove it?

Comment: use `\Comment*[f]{bar}`